# Find a path between vertices, with at most k steps between any two nodes with food

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I am trying to build a graph using Python. For every vertex, there is additional information about whether sufficient food is available at that vertex.

```
class Vertex:
    """
    Vertex represents a location in the quokka's quest to find food.
    It contains the relevant information surrounding the location.

    Attributes:
        * self.has_food (bool) - indicates whether this location has food.
        * self.edges (List[Vertex]) - list of connected vertices.
    """

    def __init__(self, has_food: bool) -> None:
        """
        Initialises this vertex, by setting the attribute whether it has food.

        :param has_food - boolean indicating whether this location has food.
        """

        self.has_food = has_food
        self.edges = []
```

In the graph class, I am trying to build a function called `find_path(s, t, k)`; this operation consists of finding a path from vertex `s` to vertex `t` such that from any location with food along this path we reach the next location with food in at most `k` steps.

I was trying to find all paths, but I get stuck on how to check whether "from any location with food along this path we reach the next location with food in at most `k` steps."

For the graph class, I already have some operations defined. They are:

- `add_vertex(v) -> bool`

  Adds the Vertex `v` to the graph, returning `True` if the operation was successful, `False` if it was not, or it was invalid.
- `fix_edge(u, v) -> bool`

  Fixes an edge between two vertices, `u` and `v`. If an edge already exists, or the edge is invalid, then this operation should return `False`. Else, if the operation succeeds, return `True`.

  Example: If an edge between u and v already exists or is invalid, `fix_edge(u, v)` should return `False`.
- `block_edge(u, v) -> bool`

  Blocks the edge between two vertices, `u` and `v`. Removes the edge if it exists, and returns `True` if the operation was successful. If the edge does not exist or is invalid, it should be unsuccessful and return `False`.

My code for `find_path(s, t, k)` looks like this and it's incomplete.

```
def find_path(self, s: Vertex, t: Vertex, k: in) -> Union[List[Vertex], None]:
    """
    find_path returns a SIMPLE path between `s` and `t` such that from any
    location with food along this path we reach the next location with food
    in at most `k` steps

    :param s - The start vertex for the quokka colony
    :param t - The destination for the quokka colony
    :param k - The maximum number of hops between locations with food, so
    that the colony can survive!
    :returns
        * The list of vertices to form the simple path from `s` to `t`
        satisfying the conditions.
        OR
        * None if no simple path exists that can satisfy the conditions, or
        is invalid.

    Example:
    (* means the vertex has food)
                *       *
        A---B---C---D---E

        1/ find_path(s=A, t=E, k=2) -> returns: [A, B, C, D, E]

        2/ find_path(s=A, t=E, k=1) -> returns: None
        (because there isn't enough food!)

        3/ find_path(s=A, t=C, k=4) -> returns: [A, B, C]

    """

    # TODO implement me please
    if k < 0:
        return False
    else:
         path = path + [s]
         if s == t:
             return [path]
         if not graph.has_key(s):
             return []
         paths = []
         for node in graph[s]:
            if node not in path:
                newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, t, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                   paths.append(newpath)
         return paths
```

Can someone help me figure out how to implement the path-finding algorithm?

Comment: I'm having trouble determining what your question is, specifically. You're not asking about how to create or modify graphs, so I don't think the info about `fix_edge`/`block_edge`/etc. is relevant. Are you asking what algorithm to use to find the paths? Or are you encountering an error or incorrect results from what you've tried so far?

Comment: Also, your formatting is out of wack. Put `\`\`\`` before and after each chunk of code so that it will display as code. Keep in mind that it shows you a live preview below the editing pane, so you can check to make sure things are displaying properly.

Comment: sorry for my unclear expression. Yes, I am asking for how to find the path which satisfies the condition of "from any location with food along this path we can reach the next location with food in at most k steps". Just like the example under def  find_path(self, s: Vertex, t: Vertex, k: in) showes.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 for your class? Python 3 removed the `.has_key()` method of dictionaries. You can use `if not s in graph` instead.